# CMS,front end,database and backend on one hosting

Tags: database, cms, self-hosted, hosted, react

I'm trying to create a website for a client and the requirements are:

- CMS to change data on the website
- backend to integrate payments and authorization
- front end
- database to store info about payments and orders

My first choice was Gatsby with datoCMS but the client wants all of these things to be hosted on his own hosting. Is this possible?
Which technology allows me to integrate all these things in one place?

Comment: What are the requirements for the front end?  What type of functioning is required?

Comment: I'm good at react framework so it would be great if the frontend could be created with react,Gatsby,next.js or something similar, right now i have this setup: 1. DatoCMS for CMS, 2. Gatsby.js for frontend, 3. Hosting and database on Firebase, 4. Backend created with cloud functions on Firebase. But i wonder if there is any better techstack,mayby all on one platform

Comment: Consider taking a look at [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/).  It can be run locally, or, on your own server.  The developer base contains lots of modules to support the functions you desire.